# PostGIS erase/difference vector polygons from raster

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql, vector

I have a raster and a vector table in Postgres 12 PostGIS 3.0

The vector polygon(orange) overlaps the slope raster(grid in black, whiteish)

[image]

All I want to do is cut out/erase the orange polygon from the black/white raster.

**My question is just focused on this specific raster and vector but in general this going to be a big process of hundreds of thousands of polygons erasing slope rasters

My process so far:

1. Convert the polygon to a raster
2. use MapAlgebra and subtract the layers which is essentially acting as a clip

query

```
drop table if exists corners.rast_test;
create table corners.rast_test as 
with a as(
SELECT ST_AsRaster(m.shape, (SELECT rast FROM corners.slope_clip LIMIT 1), '32BF', -9999) rast,id
FROM (select m.shape,m.id
from corners.mappluto m 
join corners.corners_final c on st_intersects(m.shape,c.n9x9) and m.id=2019) m
)
SELECT ST_MapAlgebra(b.rast,a.rast, '([rast1]-[rast2])') rast,cornerid
from a, corners.slope_clip  b where cornerid=1085547
```

the result

[image]

So this is the piece of the raster I do not want. I also want to keep the original slope value during this whole process

I found the expression I need to use from this question I posted about the ArcGIS Raster Calculator

```
Con(IsNull(rast2),rast1)
```

how do I turn this above expression into the correct st_mapalgebra statement

Comment: Why don't use st_clip function of postgis to clip the raster

Comment: I need the opposite of clip

Comment: need to get Pierre Racine for this question! https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/6362/pierre-racine

Comment: You want to cut the polygon or the raster??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get this right, why not `ST_Clip(rast)` the raster by the difference of the `ST_Envelope(rast)` and your *Polygon*:

```
SELECT  ST_Clip(rast, ST_Difference(ST_Envelpe(rast), <polygon_geom>), false)
FROM    <raster>,
        <poly_table>
;
```

---

This is obviously not optimized; but if running this on a large amount of rasters, it might be the more performant solution to prepare a geometry table with the actual polygons to clip by (the blade, i.e. the difference of the `ST_Envelope(rast)` and any of your polygons) including the (PK) reference to the respective raster *rid* and run the `ST_Clip(rast)` between raster and blade with matching PK/*rid*.

Comment: This is a good idea, trying it out soon!

Comment: this got me the answer but it says I need to wait 4 hours until I give you the bounty. thanks

Comment: sweet! yeah just wait until the the end, maybe someone comes up with a better answer.

Comment: although this worked do you think there is a way to do this with just rasters? like just using the map algebra?

Comment: @ziggy pretty sure, in the end you just want to set null values to some pixels...but the PostGIS raster suite is not my expertise! What I took from my time using it is to avoid touching the actual raster data as much as possible, and work with geometries wherever you can.

Comment: I will say the conversions and spatial processing between Raster and Vector is unmatched, I do not see another set of tools with its flexibility. Having said that, I find a lot of the functions to have scant documentation and there are very few advanced tutorials using PostGIS Raster